# URL Sessions returning server not found even though URL is valid - Swift4

Tags: xcode, api, nsurlsession, swift4

I am trying to use URLSession to do a API Request. The request/link is the following `https://api.nanopool.org/v1/zec/user/t1KcroGeTYz6Tn4hsgwnuiUzw65xgAAaknc`

When I put it into safari it loads. When I try preform the request in Xcode 9 with Swift4, I get an error that the server was not found.

Here is the entire error.
[image]

The top to lines are just from a print function, the rest is the error.

Here is the code I used:

```
let api = "https://api.nanopool.org/v1/zec/user/"

            let urlString = api+addr
            print(urlString)
            guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                }

                guard let data = data else { return }
                print(data)

                }.resume()
```

What is the issue with it that it causing it to return that the server cannot be found even though its a valid URL/Request?

Comment: The error message says that the host name `api.nanopool.org` cannot be resolved. Very likely the problem of the network environment of your testing device. Check the network settings or other parts of your project which may affect network settings.

Comment: Is this macOS or iOS app? If macOS app, make sure you enabled the “client” mode under the capabilities tab on your target settings.